# How to get other domain's data by using GAE

Tags: google-app-engine

We have a problem to get data from other's domain in the application

[What we want to do ]

1.get domainB's gmail(belong to himself ) in domainA
   2.get data from namespace=domainB  in domainA
   3.get domainB's google  calendar (belong to himself ) in domainA

[Condition ]

domainA is belong to parent company ,which, domainB  is belong to the child company

How can we  do this?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple options:

- create a sever to server call
- use pubsub

basically, contact the other server

Comment: Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Thanks for youe advice.

But we do have the problem on ,which is the key point
→the data to use is on the same server just has different namespace.
How can we pickup data cross the different namespace?

Comment: why would it be a problem? just passed in the namespace when you fetch it